# Defragmentation stops and does not reduce below 52%

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, defragment, maintenance

In one of my PC a single drive is not defragmenting. When i do it using windows defragmentation option the fragmentation does not reduce below 52%. I tried so many times and facing same problem. Then i checked the disk for errors using chkdsk,but didn't find any error. In that hard disk i have 4 drives.But only one drives is having this problem. Also accessing the data from that folder has become slow now. So how can i defragment it and solve the problem?

The drives size is 250 GB. Total of only 8.5 gb files are there in drive actually. But when i check the free space by right clicking-> properties it shows that 45 gb is used. But actually only 8.5 gb of file exists in the drive. Then i had doubt regarding recylebin. After clearing it also nothing changed. I have set shadow copy service to some folders in it. I think due to this free space shown is different that when i check each folder size in the drive. So what may be the error which does not reduce fragmentation?

This is the [report](http://incometaxsoft.com/analyze.txt) of defrgmentation analyze for the drive

This is the [report](http://incometaxsoft.com/after_defrgment.txt) after defrgmentation

Comment: better you backup all datas on that drive .. and reformat it !

Comment: I recall having this on an old Windows box, perhaps XP.  Never did figure out the reason, other than the defrag code was hokey.  Don't recall if I ever fixed it either -- probably just moved on.

Comment: Have you tried other defragging programs.  The built in defragging capabilities of `Windows XP` is **very limited**.

Comment: Are there lots of small files on that drive?

Comment: @matzone: Nice good old way.. :)...and arguably the fastest considering he has only 8.5GB data...

Comment: File are of average size. For that drive defragmentation was working from last one year.

Comment: @tumchaaditya : not easy to find out why the above case .. so I think this is the fastest way ..

Comment: @matzone: if I have say 1TB of data on a drive..it doubt if it would be the fastest way...

Comment: **Your defragmentation exists because of your shadow copies.**  Windows cannot be running if you want to defrag those files.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the reply. But i have so many drives which have shadow copy. For those drives i didn't face any problem.Also please see my updated question with defragmentation reports.

Comment: Have you tried defragmenting in "safe" mode?

Comment: "12              1.99 GB         \System Volume Information\,,,," basically means that a shadow copy file in use couldn't be moved.  Why don't you just **TRY** a boot time defrag to entertain us?

Comment: @DanielRHicks i have tried defragmenting in safemode.But it didnt help.

Comment: @Ramhound only 12 1.99 GB \System Volume Information or all of the \System Volume Information causing problem? Also what if i turn off vss in services.msc and try defragment?

Comment: @ITresearcher - You should try the boot time defrag before you disable the service ( no reason to disable it ) because my solution WILL work.

Answer (score 1):

Something is eating up your drive space...it surely is fragmented and is most probably locked....
Smells like system restore points.

Clear up the old system restore points.(There is an article from Microsoft which tells how to do this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555367. You can do this through CCleaner as well)
Also run CCleaner.

If that does not free up the space, use this tool to check what is eating up space: http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html

After you finish cleaning up the drive, try defragmenting it.

Comment: Ok.Just now i checked and got that the change in free space is due to shadow copy of the drive.

Comment: did you clean up the system restore points?

Comment: Do you mean have i cleared shadow copy files? The drive does not contain OS.So are you talking about shadow files?

Comment: @ITresearcher - Yes he is

Answer (score 1):

I would also check your hard drive [S.M.A.R.T. data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) report to rule out any possible hardware mechanical failures.

I once had a similar problem with a particular folder hanging up my system when accessed, and it turned out that the problem were some damaged sectors on the hard rive, which causes the system to stall when trying to read/write the file residing on the bad sectors.

There are plenty of [S.M.A.R.T. tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools), I personally suggest you [Western Digital's Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=605&sid=3&lang=it) or [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html); to understand the report, you can refer to the first Wikipedia article that I've linked.

If you discover to have some hardware related problems with your hard drive, you should consider substituting it with a new one before it becomes too damaged to be used, with consequently a potential data loss.

As a sidenote I would use a third-party defragmentation program instead of the windows default one: I usually use [Wise Disk Cleaner](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wisediskcleanerfree.html) or [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler).

Answer (score 1):

Try booting from a boot cd such as Ultimate Boot CD for Windows

It will allow you to run a defrag against files that would otherwise be locked.

It contains three 3rd party defrag programs, but im quite sure it also allows you to run the windows defrag. http://www.ubcd4win.com/contents.htm

One more trick, given enough system RAM, you can turn off your page file (reboot twice) before pushing on with the defrag.

Answer (score 0):

Defrag can not move files that are currently used. If your OS resides on this drive, 52% is not surprising.

Comment: OS is in C drive. I am having problem with D drive

Comment: @ITresearcher - You sure this just isn't the case of a very large file?

Comment: All files are small only.just now i have found some interesting with related to drive size.Please  check the updated question.

Comment: Since the gradually increase in size, they're probably shadow copies. You should probably move (or delete old copies) if you want to defrag the drive. Here's why: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312067. This next link will give you a MS tool that gives you a graphic representation of your HD: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896650